# Starred folder showing up in Mail

Tags: iphone, mail.app, gmail

I have a gmail account connected via IMAP to the iPhone 4. For some reason it shows a folder named "starred" which I cannot delete, move, nor find via the web interface in gmail. Can anyone tell me how to get rid of it?

Edit: in the properties of gmail, I have unchecked both "Important" and "Marked" folders via visible in IMAP, but that had no impact. Same goes for "All Mails", which I also cannot get rid of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starred folder is used for flagged e-mails. If you don't want this folder to show up in the mail.app you have to change the preferences directly in the Gmail web interface.

Go to *preferences* and choose the *label* tab. There you can uncheck *show in IMAP*. After the next synchronization, the folder should be gone.

[image]

Comment: That field is unmarked, yet the folder still appears.

Comment: This option does not show for Google Apps for Business accounts

Comment: This option is present only if you check IMAP access in Forwarding and POP/IMAP settings